# Unable to replace in String java ?

Tags: java

I am unable to replace part of the substring in my code ? I want to get rid of the unwanted characters but i still get the same output ?

```
String BusDetails = "ROUTE 3  &#151; CLEARBROOK-UFV GOLINE TO UFV" ;
System.out.println("BusDetails before"+BusDetails);
BusDetails.replaceAll("&#151;", "");
System.out.println("BusDetails After"+BusDetails);


// Output 
BusDetails before ROUTE 3  &#151; CLEARBROOK-UFV GOLINE TO UFV
BusDetails After ROUTE 3  &#151; CLEARBROOK-UFV GOLINE TO UFV
```

Comment: you need to *assign back* the output of `BusDetails.replaceAll("&#151;", "");` to `BusDetails`

Comment: Side note: Make sure you stick to java naming conventions. Variables should start with a lowercase, and class names should start with an uppercase and be CamelCase. So `BusDetails` should be named `busDetails`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java strings are immutable.  You need to do this:

```
BusDetails = BusDetails.replaceAll("&#151;", "");
```

Also: "standard practice" is to name variables with a lowercase first letter `busDetails`.

Answer (score 0):

```
BusDetails= BusDetails.replaceAll("&#151;", "");
```

you forgot to re assign variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to put 'replaced value' into another variable. Example below compiled code:

```
String busDetails = "ROUTE 3  &#151; CLEARBROOK-UFV GOLINE TO UFV" ;
System.out.println("BusDetails before :"+busDetails);
String replacetxt = busDetails.replaceAll("&#151; ", "");
System.out.println("BusDetails After :"+replacetxt);
```